# custom library of standard workflow activities in Wf4

Tags: wix, custom-controls, add-in, workflow-foundation-4

We have developed several wf4 custom activities that we want to provide to customers to work with in their solutions.

We are thinking in a workflow extension SDK that can reference the libraries in customer solutions as well as see the activities in the toolbox of the workflow designer.

What is the best approach to that goal? Wix? A VS2K10 add-in solution? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case it still could help anyone,

Finally we developed a 2K12 .Visx package that reads through the libraries of the projects. If any of those is an activity library we put those activities in the toolbox.

Definitively, visx packages combined with EnvDTE references are a powerful combination even though there is not much documentation out there.